# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with any URL beginning with: chrome-extension://

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Specifically I want that when I open a new tab, the [Read Later Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/read-later/nplngmgdacdfncdkpdomipkehfnbinfa) will open. Why? Because I prefer to read some interesting thing that I saved for later instead of being distracted by other websites.

I've tried with several extensions to redirect to the Read Later Chrome app URL when a new tab is open, but I got the same error always. This is the URL by the way: chrome-extension://ffkmmgcnbjamaacfolbfodfpcepapmnp/main.html

**I've tried on incognito window with all extensions disabled, but it didn't work.**

I've realised that the problem occur with any URL beginning with chrome-extension://

The error is:

> ffkmmgcnbjamaacfolbfodfpcepapmnp is blockedRequests to the server have
> been blocked by an extension. Try disabling your extensions.
> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Two examples of extensions tried:

- ProductivityTab — Custom New Tab Dashboard: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/productivitytab-%E2%80%94-custom/iccjgbbjckehppnpajnmplcccjcgbdep
- Custom New Tab URL: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-new-tab-url/mmjbdbjnoablegbkcklggeknkfcjkjia

Screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

I also asked in Github by the way: https://github.com/napsternxg/ReadLater/issues/38

I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6. Chrome Version 86.0.4240.193 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Do you have found any solution?

Comment: @gypsicoder nope, sorry

Comment: Same problem here developing a chrome-extension T_T